# Using rm -rf with a directory

Tags: bash, directory, rm

I tried to search on SO, but not able to find the difference between the following commands.   if I have a directory named dir,  how the below commands differ?

- `rm -rf dir/*`
- `rm -rf dir/`
- `rm -rf dir`

Also how do the user permissions on the directory affect the outcome, if the id running the command is not the owner or not even in the group of the owner?

I am adding the command to do rm -rf in a shell script I am working on and need help in understanding the difference between the above commands.

Comment: Please ask your sysadmin or ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @Cyrus "ask your sysadmin". Not sure I agree with this advice. Equally, we could say "ask a senior developer" when people ask programming questions

Comment: Granted, but the pointer to SuperUser is much less open to debate/dispute; this isn't a question about the process of writing software, or about tools specific to that purpose. (http://unix.stackexchange.com/ could also qualify as a topical forum).

Comment: Just curious, is shell scripting related question considered a professional programming question? So, if I had mentioned that I am adding the command to do rm -rf in a shell script I am working on and need help in understanding the difference between the above commands - would it have qualified to be a valid SO question?

Comment: @adbdkb, questions that are principally about scripting are certainly on-topic here, yes. By contrast, questions about general usage with no particular applicability to scripting (beyond the fact that those commands could potentially be used in scripts) are more applicable elsewhere. Just mentioning that your intended use is a script doesn't make that difference, but if you were asking about a use pattern of `rm` that doesn't come up in general interactive usage (say, you wanted to delete all files named in a NUL-delimited stream), it'd be topical.

Comment: See also meta discussions, for example [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226036/is-bash-on-topic-or-not), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/should-the-batch-file-programming-questions-be-moved-from-so-to-sf) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132402/shell-programming-question-moved-to-super-user?noredirect=1&lq=1) - I'd conclude from that "scripting is on topic for Stack Overflow, interactive use less so", but I wouldn't say it's clear cut.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `rm -rf dir/*`

  Removes files within the directory (without removing the directory itself).
  **Note**, [hidden files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) won't be removed.
- `rm -rf dir/`

  Trailing slash indicates that `dir` is a directory. If it was a file, it wouldn't get removed. In your case this is identical to `rm -rf dir`, but in general it differs (see below)
- `rm -rf dir`

  In your case, identical to the one above.

In general, tools such as `rm` usually follow [IEEE/OpenGroup standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12) when it comes to pathname resolution, which means that `dir/` is equivalent to `dir/.`. One implication of that is that if `dir`is a symlink to a directory `rm -rf dir/` will remove the content of the directory (including the hidden files) but not the link or the directory itself, whereas `rm -rf dir` will only remove the symlink.

You need to have `write` permissions on a file or directory that you are removing, plus `exec` permissions on a directory that `rm` needs to traverse to remove files. You can read more about Unix filesystem permissions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work/21252#21252).

Comment: So, considering the permissions to be valid to perform the action, the second and the third commands from my question or the response above - **`rm -rf dir/`**    and    **`rm -rf dir`**    will both also remove the directory?

Comment: @adbdkb yes, that should be the case.